# Prove $ \int \frac{d^d k}{k^2} \propto \int k^{d-3} dk$

Tags: integration

I have recently started wondering about the [Mermin-Wagner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem) and the correction of the first-order leads to the following integral:
 $$ \int \frac{d^d k}{k^2}$$
And it is said in the Wikipedia article that it is proportional to:
$$ \int k^{d-3} dk$$
Which proves the Mermin-Wagner theorem

However, I did not understand which change of variable got applied to turn an integral of dimension $d$ into an integral of dimension $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spherical coordinates is used to express $d^d k = k^{d-1} dk\, d\sigma$, where $d\sigma$ is the surface element of the $(d-1)$-sphere. Then $$\int \frac{d^d k}{k^2} = \int d\sigma \int \frac{k^{d-1}\, dk}{k^2} = C_d \int k^{d-3}\, dk$$ where $C_d$ is the surface area of the $(d-1)$-sphere.